# Jenkins on Windows Server vs Windows Client

Tags: windows, jenkins, continuous-integration

I was asked to find out best configurations for a Jenkins CI server for our company. M< hardware configuration ideas are pretty complete by now (Jenkins master running in VM, with multiple PC slaves), however I cannot decide on which OS I should use for the master.

Possible is a Windows 7 client or a Windows 8 Server (2012 I tihnk), that's what our IT says. Does one of those two have a small or big advantage over the other for running the Jenkins master on it?

Due to the fact, that I am not very familiar with the Windows server family, the only thing that came to my head was, that multiple remote access works on Server without getting conflicts with the IT department. But that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have Jenkins on **Windows XP**, **7**, **Server 2008** and **Linux CentOS**. Some virtual and some physical.
All setups work well for us.
You just need to understand what your need is from the Jenkins instance.
Think about backup, up time, disaster recovery, security and access management.
What do you want to build and in what environment.

Jenkins will work well on any platform as long as you match your needs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so far. Builds are planned to be done on separate machines. The Jenkins is only (so my idea) used to allocate jobs on slaves and for user management. It supposed to be turned on all the time....What differences are there in security management? Why is backup behavior different?  ... looks like I still don't know enough. This is our first try with CI :/

Comment: As far as security and backup, the server versions might have built in tools for this and might have better support from local IT. You can also do it with a simple desktop version of Windows XP...